# Move values down in a Matrix C

Tags: c

I'm still a noob at programming and still don't know many of the functions that I'm able to use so I kept to the basics, I was trying to create the game 2048 in C, for that I decided to make a function to push numbers in certain directions, either upwards, downwards, left or right. My up function is working, but my down function isn't even though I did the opposite of what I did in my up function. In the push_down function the numbers actually do what they do in the push_up functions, they move up instead of down.

Would love to know why it isn't working if anyone can spot my mistake

```
//this one is working
void push_up(int game_size, int grid[game_size][game_size])
{
    int replace;
    int num=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < game_size ; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < game_size ; ++i)
        {
            replace = 100;
            if(grid[i][j]==0)                
            {
                for (int a = game_size - 1 ; a > 0 + i ; --a) 
                {
                    if(grid[a][j]!=0)
                    {
                        num=grid[a][j];
                        replace=a;

                    }
                }
                grid[i][j]=num; 
                num=0;
            }
            if(replace!=100){
            grid[replace][j]=0;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// this one isn't working
void push_down(int game_size, int grid[game_size][game_size])
{
    int replace;
    int num=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < game_size ; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = game_size - 1; i >= 0 ; --i) 
        {
            replace = 100;
            if(grid[i][j]==0)               
            {
                for (int a = 0 ; a < game_size - i ; ++a) 
                {
                    if(grid[a][j]!=0)
                    {
                        num=grid[a][j];
                        replace=a;

                    }
                }
                grid[i][j]=num; //
                num=0;
            }
            if(replace!=100){
            grid[replace][j]=0;  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I did in both is mainly to run the column(either upwards or downwards depending on the function) trying to find a zero, lock the position of the  zero and try to find the next number in that column by running the column in the opposite direction, the last number (if a number was even found) would be used to fill that zero and the position where the number was would be filled with 0.

So, let me give an example of what I wanted with these function:

In the first function (push_up) I wanted and was able to do a function that would transform this matrix :

4 2 4 0
0 0 0 0
0 4 2 2
2 0 4 2

into this one:

4 2 4 2
2 4 2 2
0 0 4 0
0 0 0 0

So, all the values would move to the highest position possible inside the column.

In the second function what I wanted was to transform this matrix:

4 2 4 0
0 0 0 0
0 4 2 2
2 0 4 2

into this one:

0 0 0 0
0 0 4 0
4 2 2 2
2 4 4 2

All the values would move to the lowest possible position inside the matrix. But I wasn't able to, by running the function what I get is:

This is the original matrix:

0 0 0 0

4 0 0 2

2 0 0 4

0 2 0 0

This is the matrix after using the function push_down:

2 2 0 4

4 0 0 2

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

There are probably easier ways to do this, I would love to hear them but I would also love to know where my logic went wrong in the push_down function since in the push_up function it's working fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. "isn't working" is never a good problem description. Describe in what ways it is not working. Does it crash? Does it get wrong results sometimes? Wrong results all the time? etc. Also, it's an SO requirement to provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for all debugging requests.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't reproducible and I'm not certain exactly what you're trying to do, but this is the obvious error:

```
for (int a = 0 ; a > game_size - i ; ++a) 
  {
    if(grid[a][j]!=0)
    {
      num=grid[a][j];
      replace=a;

    }
}
```

This loop will never run, `a` is zero and will never be greater than `game_size - 1`.

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake when copying the code to SO, after changing it it's still not working, I added a couple of examples to see if it's easier to understand what I wanted with the function push_down, also added an example of it running.

Comment: @Teutonium You're best of providing a [Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for people to use rather than just the problem function. People are more likely to help with code that compiles that they can just pop into a debugger than try to reason through your code off SO.